# Dictation input on the simulator

Tags: ios, uitextfield, ios-simulator, dictation

Is it possible to have dictation input for a UITextField on the iOS simulator? If so, what do I need to do? 
The device I have available for development is the iPhone 4, which I don't think supports dictation input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the simulator does not support dictation. Neither does the iPhone 4.

Comment: Do you have any link to the iOS developer documentation that states this? I suspected it to be the case, but couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: No link but I can run the simulator and see that there is no option for dictation. :) Plus, a Google search for the subject comes up with no solutions. And no one here has posted a solution.